# Execute org mode code block without escape codes

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I run a bash code block I get a response which contains a lot of escape codes/sequences, which makes the results output less readable. Example below:

[image: example code block output with escape codes/sequences]

How can execute the code block, without the ugly escape codes being included?

Comment: You could treat it in bash by removing escape sequences (e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172000/remove-escape-characters-using-sed ) or treat it in Org using :post to cleanup the output.

Comment: See if `terraform` has an option to omit them. E.g `ls` has a `--color=never` option to avoid  producing color codes. There also may exist an environment variable that controls this (e.g. `LS_COLORS` does this for `ls`).

Comment: @NickD, thanks, that did the trick (at least for terraform), will figure out other solutions for other commands where this is happening

Comment: if you use the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378271/how-do-i-display-ansi-color-codes-in-emacs-for-any-mode , you wont see the ugly codes, but the corresponding colours